# Block sealing failed waiting for transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I have problem on running a node on my local machine.

I have installed Geth from Homebrew by running this command `brew install ethereum`

Whenever I call this command `geth --dev --mine` in terminal I get this log:

`INFO [03-16|17:40:15] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Using developer account                  address=0x9637858cA3f5B1761DfC5aD5d76539e44B128614
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.8.2-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.10
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=12 size=2.26kB time=19.413µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1337 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: <nil> Engine: clique}"
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=d529a9…d91f92 td=1
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=d529a9…d91f92 td=1
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=d529a9…d91f92 td=1
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Starting P2P networking 
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] RLPx listener up                         self="enode://6601a763fa9cfb8bde516a1e68fc71bc7e6d30bc85400d5de61ef59459cd95289a598e48e5f1d41dba561e209224d51090933f8ff5b9a679895ce7b63023ed70@[::]:60117?discport=0"
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] started whisper v.5.0 
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0x9637858cA3f5B1761DfC5aD5d76539e44B128614
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Starting mining operation 
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/var/folders/gt/l9r08rns0dxf_zz733dq9dsm0000gn/T/geth.ipc
INFO [03-16|17:40:17] Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=68.51µs
WARN [03-16|17:40:17] Block sealing failed                     err="waiting for transactions"`

Main error seems to be this one `WARN Block sealing failed  err="waiting for transactions"`

Geth
Version: 1.8.2-stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning that you are seeing is because the `--dev` flag creates a Proof of Authority chain (and not a Proof of Work one). From the [CLI documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options):

```
DEVELOPER CHAIN OPTIONS:
--dev               Ephemeral proof-of-authority network with a pre-funded developer account, mining enabled
```

[Looking at the `clique` codebase](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f8888e11606296c9582496974c0f6b96a882146/consensus/clique/clique.go#L132), you will see that this is an optimisation to reduce the size of the network:

```
// errWaitTransactions is returned if an empty block is attempted to be sealed
// on an instant chain (0 second period). It's important to refuse these as the
// block reward is zero, so an empty block just bloats the chain... fast.
errWaitTransactions = errors.New("waiting for transactions")
```

**It does not look like this warning is anything to worry about.**